# Improving performance of reading 2's complement of integers

Tags: performance, optimization, vb6

I have an inefficient VB6 function to read 2's complement integers.

```
Private Function Mantis(ByVal HiByte As Byte, ByVal LoByte As Byte, ByVal Range As Single) As Single

    Dim bSam As Integer
    Dim Bits(15) As Boolean

    bSam = (HiByte And &H7F) * &H100 Or LoByte Or (HiByte \ &H80) * &H8000

    Bits(15) = bSam And 32768

    If Bits(15) Then
        If bSam = -32768 Then
            bSam = 0
        Else
            bSam = bSam * -1
        End If
    End If

    Dim I As Integer

    For I = 0 To 14
        Bits(I) = bSam And (2 ^ I)
    Next

    Dim bOut As Long

    If Bits(2) Then bOut = bOut + 5
    If Bits(3) Then bOut = bOut + 10
    If Bits(4) Then bOut = bOut + 20
    If Bits(5) Then bOut = bOut + 39
    If Bits(6) Then bOut = bOut + 78
    If Bits(7) Then bOut = bOut + 156
    If Bits(8) Then bOut = bOut + 313
    If Bits(9) Then bOut = bOut + 625
    If Bits(10) Then bOut = bOut + 1250
    If Bits(11) Then bOut = bOut + 2500
    If Bits(12) Then bOut = bOut + 5000
    If Bits(13) Then bOut = bOut + 10000
    If Bits(14) Then bOut = bOut + 20000
    If Bits(15) Then bOut = bOut * -1

    Mantis = bOut * Range

End Function
```

How can I improve it performance-wise? I think it could be replaced by some `memcpy` or other API calls, but I don't know which one. Because right now it has to test each individual bit.

Answer (score 0):

VB6's Integer type is 16-bit signed two's complement so I'm not sure what all of the bit fiddling is needed for.

Why not something simple like this if your data arrives as two Byte values:

```
Private Type IntAsBytes
    LoByte As Byte
    HiByte As Byte
End Type

Private Type IntAsInt
    Int As Integer
End Type

Private Function Mantis( _
    ByVal HiByte As Byte, _
    ByVal LoByte As Byte, _
    ByVal Range As Single) As Single

    Dim AsBytes As IntAsBytes
    Dim AsInt As IntAsInt

    AsBytes.LoByte = LoByte
    AsBytes.HiByte = HiByte
    LSet AsInt = AsBytes
    Mantis = CSng(AsInt.Int) * Range
End Function
```